# Batch Class execute method

Tags: batch

I have created a Batch class and write a logic into execute method. In this logic I queried a Object (DuplicateRecordItem) . It's giving an error on saving the batch class Error:(sObject type 'DuplicateRecordItem' is not supported). I can not understand why this showing. My logic is below Please Help!

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<DuplicateRecordSet> scope) {

    //call MergeAccounts method.
    MergeAccounts(scope); 
}  

public static void  MergeAccounts(List<DuplicateRecordSet> dupset){

    Map<Id, DuplicateRecordSet> mapDuplicateRecordSet =  new Map<Id,DuplicateRecordSet>();

    for(DuplicateRecordSet drs : dupset){
        mapDuplicateRecordSet.put(drs.Id, drs);
    }

    Map<Id, Set<Id>> mapDuplicateRecordItem =  new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();

    //here throwing error 
    for(DuplicateRecordItem drI : [SELECT Id,RecordId, DuplicateRecordSetId FROM DuplicateRecordItem where DuplicateRecordSetId In : mapDuplicateRecordSet.keyset()]){

        if(!mapDuplicateRecordItem.containskey(drI.DuplicateRecordSetId)){
            mapDuplicateRecordItem.put(drI.DuplicateRecordSetId, new Set<Id>{drI.RecordId}); 
        }
        else{
            mapDuplicateRecordItem.get(drI.DuplicateRecordSetId).add(drI.RecordId); 
        }
    } 

    for(DuplicateRecordSet dr : [SELECT Id FROM DuplicateRecordSet where Id IN : mapDuplicateRecordItem.keyset()]){

        Set<Id>  setaccId =  mapDuplicateRecordItem.get(dr.Id);

        list<id> lstAccId = new list<id>(); 

        for(Account acc : [SELECT Id, name,BillingCountry, BillingState FROM Account where ID In : setaccId And OwnerId ='00540000002lBne' Limit 1]){

                setaccId.remove(acc.Id);  
                lstAccId.addAll(setaccId);  
                merge acc lstAccId;
                break; 
            } 
        }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your class is saved at API version 32.0 or above, `DuplicateRecordItem` did not come in until version 32.0.